# select top 5 in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have

```
[Person]
PersonID, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName

[OnlineAccount]
OnlineAccountID, PersonID, Nickname
```

Each person is allowed to have 0-* OnlineAccount.

In entity framework with C#, how do I select the top 5 Person that has the most accounts?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Try this:

```
var items = context.PersonSet.OrderByDescending(u => u.OnlineAccounts.Count).Take(5);
```

This returns `IQueryable<Person>`. It doesn't return results yet, because it implements deferred execution. It will be translated to SQL and executed when needed:

```
var metarializedItems = items.ToList(); // ToList forces execution
```

or

```
foreach(var item in items) // foreach forces execution
```

Example above will translate to SQL similar to this one:

```
SELECT TOP 5 p.PersonID, p.EmailAddress, p.FirstName, p.LastName 
FROM Person p
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OnlineAccount oa WHERE p.PersonID = oa.PersonID) DESC
```

It won't be this exact SQL. Different EF version may produce different SQLs, but I wrote it to ilustrate how it works. `Take(5)` is translated to `TOP 5`. `OrderByDescending(u => u.OnlineAccounts.Count)` is translated to `ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OnlineAccount oa WHERE p.PersonID = oa.PersonID) DESC`. This is power of Entity Framework. It translates .NET expressions to SQL.

Comment: Will this actually end up as a `SELECT TOP 5...` query against the database?

Comment: @Peter Lillevold: Yes. It will take only 5 rows in query execution.

Comment: @LukLed Are you certain of that? You mean that the EF doesn't fulfill its execution first before the IEnumerable extension method processes? I'm not sure that's true....

Comment: @MatthewPK: I am not sure how to convice you:) Please take SQL profiler and check. You'll see only 5 rows taken from database:)

Comment: @LukLed confirmed with LinqPad, +1!

Comment: awesome.  Was scared there wouldn't be away without pulling them all

Comment: yes ! this is so useful ! Whenever things get too heavy and your request times out, you can use this to lighten the datas, and while it works, you can easely think of another solution.