# Entity Framework - To sum reference object properties

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following models which represent my table relationship.

```
public class A { List<B> B_List }
public class B { public int amount }
```

I was wondering if it is possible to get top 5 class A objects order by "amount".

I was hoping there is a way to write an EF query to avoid pulling all A objects from database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select top 5 in entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656576/select-top-5-in-entity-framework)

Comment: `dbContext.AList
    .OrderBy(a=>Math.Max(a.B_List.Select(b=>b.amount)))
    .Take(5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Bilal's answer is close, but may not get you exactly what you want.  By the way, you haven't been clear on what you mean by "top 5 A objects order by Amount".  Each A object has multiple amounts.  Are you wanting the top 5 A objects based on the maximum amount?  If so, then try this ...

```
dbContext.AList
.OrderByDescending(a => a.B_List.Sum(b => b.amount))
.Take(5);
```

Comment: sorry, i meant top 5 based on sum of Amount