# Full Dataset rather than Top 1000 EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to return the top 1000 rows from a table, however using EF Core, I am getting the full dataset before the .Take(1000) runs.

***API***

```
[HttpGet("MyThing/{id}")]
public List<MyObj> ItemsReport(long id)
{
    response = new List<MyObj>();
    response = _reporting.GetNewEntries(id);
    return response;
}
```

***Reporting***

```
public virtual List<MyObj> GetNewEntries(long id)
{
    var newEntries = new List<MyObj>();

    var entries = _DbContext.ReportNewEntries
                            .OrderBy(a => long.Parse(a.Id))
                            .Where(a => long.Parse(a.Id) > id)
                            .Take(1000);

    newEntries.AddRange(entries);

    return newEntries;
}
```

***DbContext***

```
DbSet<MyObj> ReportNewEntries{ get; set; }
```

My desired query is something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) * 
FROM dbo.ReportNewEntries 
WHERE CONVERT(bigint, Id) > 0 
ORDER BY CONVERT(bigint, Id)
```

My current query, as per SQL profiler is:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ReportNewEntries
```

The table is monolithic, so I want to access the rows 1000 at a time. Any suggestions to the what mistake I am making?

Comment: It is not clear what is the issue your code already returns only 1000 row from the table

Comment: Tried `var entries = _DbContext.ReportNewEntries.Take(1000).OrderBy(a => long.Parse(a.Id)).Where(a => long.Parse(a.Id) > id);`?

Comment: @AhmedYousif the question clearly states the problem isn't what the code returns, it's what query it runs below.

Comment: it should not because the statement won't executed until try to resolve it or call .ToList() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656576/select-top-5-in-entity-framework

Comment: @AhmedYousif - but it is, I have sql profiler running, and it is.

Comment: @bolkay this works somewhat, however, I need to get the top 1000 after I have the first set, for example, row 1-1000 loads, I recall 1001-2000 with the Id so I get the next 1000. Does that make sense?

Comment: @N00b instead of long.parse use Convert.ToInt64 and try again

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `List`, you're using **Linq-To-Object**, which works on `IEnumerable`.

And, indeed, `IEnumerable` will first load all the data in memory before applying Take to it.

What you want to use is `IQueryable`, which is **Linq-to-Sql**.

So either modify your methods to return a `IQueryable<MyObj>`, or call your Linq chain with `AsQueryable()`like this:

```
var entries = _DbContext.ReportNewEntries.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(a => long.Parse(a.Id)).Where(a => long.Parse(a.Id) > id).Take(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? What version of .NetCore? What db provider? Some db providers might have issues translating some linq statements into sql. In this case, will run a different query in database (usually take all the data) and perform the linq in memory.